# Trial Subscription order numbers

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing

According to [Google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#orderId), `orderId` field of the `INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA` should be formatted in a way that you can figure out an recurrence number from it.

```
"GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567" (base order number)
"GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567..0" (first recurrence orderID)
"GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567..1" (second recurrence orderID)
"GPA.1234-5678-9012-34567..2" (third recurrence orderID)
```

When it comes to free trials, things get unclear. I would expect the behaviour to follow the same pattern:

1. user starts a trial, orderId will be **base order** number
2. trial ends and user is charged for the first time, orderId will
   indicate **first recurrence**

As test purchases don't include orderId, the only way to test this is to start a real trial and check results in (minimum) seven days. 
Can therefore anyone confirm this?

Further on, let's say user cancels trial immediately and starts a subscription right after that? Google will make sure user gets charged and all, but will orderId be a base order again or next recurrence?